What is the odor of rosin solder No-Clean wire?
Decades ago, I got a small spool of Kester 60/40 rosin core 0.031 solder. It's so old, it doesn't have a part number anywhere that I can determine (except maybe little "93" on the bottom of the back label).  It just says "Hi-Tech Electronic Rosin Core Solder". It perfectly fit my use.
A few years ago, I purchased a spool of Qualitek 50-60521 60/40 1.1% Flux, no clean.
It stinks when melting into connections. I mean smell wise, it makes me gag when using it. I have to hold my breath while soldering, and duck under my workbench to grab a breath.  Otherwise, it's given me sore throat issues when I use it for a couple dozen or more connections.
I'm not enthusiastic to install a vent hood in my home workshop. I doubt it could suck out the fumes fast enough anyway. I'd like to buy a spool that doesn't produce this odor, like my old Kester.  And continue to just leave a door open and use a fan.
Is the cause of the odor from whatever is used as a no-clean additive?  That appears to be the only difference between the two products that I can determine.
My decades old spool of Kester is running low, and I want to purchase another spool of something that doesn't produce such a smell.  So before I buy more spools as a "trial and error", I'd ask.
No web searches I've come up with cover this issue.
Any information is appreciated.



If you were ok with the smell of the rosin flux, get more rosin core solder. However be aware that breathing in flux fumes, even if you don't mind the smell, is fairly bad for your lungs. If smell is a factor in your buying decisions I strongly recommend getting a fume extractor or improving your ventilation.

@user1850479  Thanks.   But what is amazing to me is that the Kester is pheromonally milder (less intense) compared to the Qualitek.  I'm not sure why.  Or even if the manufacturing process of normal 60/40 solder has changed over the decades.

Get an exhaust fan with filter. There are decent ones available for $100 or you can get hobbyist ones for 20 to $30 which you're essentially a fan in the filter

Rosin core is not no-clean (although, as they say, for many applications you don't actually need to remove it).
This is not a medical recommendation, but I would suggest buying solder with RA rosin core such as Kester 44 (probably what you have). 'No clean' often also leaves an invisible nasty slightly electrically leaky residue on the board that is very difficult to remove. It's okay for ordinary products, but causes problems with extremely precise or low current instruments.
And get some kind of extractor, fan or filter to avoid breathing most of that junk. The more you solder the more you need that. You can DIY it if you don't have the budget (and at current solder prices you may not have much left..)
63/37 (eutectic) is a preferred alloy to 60/40 because it solidifies at a sharp temperature point rather than over a range, lowering the likelihood of a 'cold' solder joint if something moves as it is solidifying. It's generally slightly more expensive because tin costs more than lead.

I'm just a hobbyist, not a lot of soldering, except in "sprints" every month or so. 63/37 is most of what is available now anyway.  My extraction right now is to leave the door open (into a garage), and run a fan.

A quiet little fan with a filter right next to the soldering (sucking, not blowing) will avoid that otherwise inevitable wisp of flux fumes that always seems drawn to the solderer's nose.

I seem to have an alleregic reaction to some older fluxes.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany  Although my question was "Is the reason for a worse smell from the 'noClean' chemicals?", I purchased a Weller fan, $110 at DigiKey, but $60 on Amazon.  I will buy regular Kester 63/37 as well, to see if the stronger and harsh smell remains (I thought Rosin is supposedly only tree sap based)

@SpacemanScott 'No Clean' flux is not rosin like Kester 44, it's something else and I can well imagine it might smell worse or be more unhealthy than rosin. I don't use it at all (some suppliers do, however) so I can't comment on the aroma, and in any case it would be somewhat subjective. Here is the SDS for Kester 958 "low residue" flux. The toxicological info is not really evaluated under soldering conditions from what I can see.
